# Call a function on elements with specific css class angular2 equivalent of jquery

Tags: jquery, css, angular, each, selector

so I have two components which are a Parent and a Child Component. The Parent Component references the child component with this below code and also has this constructor.

```
@ViewChild('nouislider') nouislider: any;


constructor(private util: UtilService, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.nouislider.el);
    this.nouislider.slider.on('start', function(){
        console.log("hello");
    });
}
```

So my question is: how can I do the equivalent of the following jquery code using only angular2? Basically, using angular to select a class and call a function on elements with that class?

```
$('#slider-tooltip').noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'values',
    values: [500000,1000000,3000000,5000000,10000000],
    density: 4
});

$('.noUi-value.noUi-value-horizontal.noUi-value-large').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).html();
    val = recountVal(parseInt(val));
    $(this).html(val);
});

function recountVal(val){
    switch(val){
        case 500000: return '< $500 K'; break;
        case 1000000:return '$1 M';break;
        case 3000000:return '$3 M';break;
        case 5000000:return '$5 M';break;
        default :return '$10 M';break;
    }
}
```

Here is the nouislider component

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <nouislider #nouislider [step]="step" [format]="format" [tooltips]="[ true , true ]" [connect]="true" [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue" [(ngModel)]="someRange" (change)="onSlide()"></nouislider>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="ninetyDaysError">Dates must be within 90 days of each other.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4><div class="label label-primary">{{days}}</div></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `nouislider` an angular component?  Please show the component if so.

Comment: @ChrisG I have posted the html. The nouislider is an open source project, the component is found here: https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `nouislider` variable is of type `NouisliderComponent`.  This means that you can call any methods on that component that you wish.

Additionally, you can pass in a formatter of type `NouiFormatter` which implements the following methods: `to(value: number): string;` `from(value: string): number;`

So you can make a custom formatter which you pass to your component via `[format]="myCustomFormatter"`.  Your format would take in 500000 and return '< $500 K' and so on for your specific values.